# Outline view fill with Core Data

Tags: macos, core-data, swift3

i would like to create a NSOutlineView with swift 3 for macOS.
therefore i found a youtube tutorial, which bring me to this good result:

[image]

but the data of this outline view is static.
now i would like to fill the outline view with data from core data.

i know core data and i know how i can fetch data from it.
but i dont know how i can dynamic fill it into outline view.

this is my code at the moment:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var treeController: NSTreeController!
    @IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addData()
    }

    func addData() {
        let root: [String : Any] = [ "name": "Max Mustermann", "isLeaf": false ]
        let dict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: root)
        dict.setObject([Test()], forKey: "children" as NSCopying)

        treeController.addObject(dict)
    }
    func isHeader(item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        if let item = item as? NSTreeNode {
            return !(item.representedObject is Test)
        } else {
            return !(item is Test)
        }
    }
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        if isHeader(item: item as AnyObject) {
            return outlineView.make(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell", owner: self)
        } else {
            return outlineView.make(withIdentifier: "DataCell", owner: self)
        }
    }


}
```

**Playlist.swift**
import Cocoa

```
class Playlist: NSObject {

dynamic var name: String = "New Playlist"

func isLeaf() -> Bool {
return true
    }

}
```

i hope you can help me :)

```
var result = [Test]()

        let appdelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Test")

        do {
            result = try context.fetch(request) as! [Test]
        } catch { }
```

Comment: Do a Core Data tutorial also. https://www.raywenderlich.com/145809/getting-started-core-data-tutorial

Comment: yeah, i know how i can fetch data from coredata. but how i fill it into the outline view?

Comment: Replace `[Playlist()]` with `[fetchedResults]` and all occurrences of `Playlist` with `YourEntity` . If you run into issues, update your question with what you have tried. Try to _understand_ the posted code.

Comment: sry but my code doesn't work with your solution. i do it 100% wrong. can you show me the correct full answer so i can learn from it, please? i am very sry :'(

Comment: i updated my first post with my core data fetch code

Comment: Your fetch looks good. Now update your code to use `Test` instead of `Playlist`.

Comment: i updated the viewcontroller.swift in post 1. is it correctly?

Comment: I don't know :-) Do you have any issues? If so, which? `[Test()]` is definitely wrong. As said, use `[fetchedResults]`

Comment: in my case it has to be `[request]` or `[result]` instead of `[fetchedResults]`, isn't it?

Comment: You start to get it.

Comment: okay first issue: if i start the application, i see in first row "Max Mustermann". if i expand it, the app crashes: `2017-05-05 21:45:27.741295+0200 Programm[63569:3322467] [General] [<_TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStorageC8Programm6Test_ 0x608000261640> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: isLeaf`